# bootstrap modal box in nav-pills not working on second and others

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

Is there something wrong with my Jquery or Bootstrap callings?
i have downloaded the jquery.min.js and its coming from my local directory.
It was working fine before and i guess there i made some change in some script calling not sure though. Its working on the first Nav-pill but not on the other.
There is no error for Jquery on the console what else could be the problem?

```
<html>
<head>

    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <title>Research Group</title>

    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="apple-touch-icon.png">

    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap-3.3.5-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>

    <script src="js/plugins.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-3.3.5-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">

</head>
<body>
<header>
    <?php require_once('header.php');?>
</header>
<div class="container" style="margin-top: 200px;">
    <!-- Nav tabs -->
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
        <li class="active"><a href=".home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href=".profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
        <li><a href=".messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
        <li><a href=".settings" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
    </ul>

    <!-- Tab panes -->
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active home">home
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

            <!-- Modal -->
            <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
                <div class="modal-dialog">

                    <!-- Modal content-->
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div></div>
        <div class="tab-pane profile">profile
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

            <!-- Modal -->
            <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
                <div class="modal-dialog">

                    <!-- Modal content-->
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div></div>
        <div class="tab-pane messages">messages
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

            <!-- Modal -->
            <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
                <div class="modal-dialog">

                    <!-- Modal content-->
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div></div>
        <div class="tab-pane settings">settings</div>
    </div>


    <hr>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You've given both modals the same ID. Just give the second modal a unique ID (and change the data-target for profile to match that). As an aside, you also don't need to add both jquery.min.js and jquery-1.11.2.min.js. Just use one.

Comment: sorry which id ? are you talking about `id = "myModal" ` ?

Comment: @LoftyGrain here is an example http://jsfiddle.net/44k6962y/ yeah you have to change `data-target="#myModal"` and here `<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">`, `ids` must be unique

Comment: Yes, that one. Pretty much what Shehary said.

Comment: @BSMP, you should posted the answer, consider these easy questions as bonus points :)

Comment: Yea thanks for that help guys i really appreciate it but why someone gave me -1?
What does that suppose to do where we should get to know to give the different ID. That's really demotivating

Comment: @shehary i'll still  up vote BSMP comment

Answer (score 1):

Your `data-target="#myModal"` needs to match and be unique for each modal > `id="myModal"`. See example.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container" style="margin-top: 200px;">
  <!-- Nav tabs -->
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li class="active"><a href=".home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a>

    </li>
    <li><a href=".profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a>

    </li>
    <li><a href=".messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a>

    </li>
    <li><a href=".settings" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a>

    </li>
  </ul>
  <!-- Tab panes -->
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active home">home
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>
      <!-- Modal -->
      <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
          <!-- Modal content-->
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
              <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane profile">profile
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2">Open Modal</button>
      <!-- Modal -->
      <div id="myModal2" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
          <!-- Modal content-->
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
              <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane messages">messages
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal3">Open Modal</button>
      <!-- Modal -->
      <div id="myModal3" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
          <!-- Modal content-->
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
              <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane settings">settings</div>
  </div>
  <hr>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the true solution actually

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container" style="margin-top: 200px;">
  <!-- Nav tabs -->
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li class="active"><a href=".home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a>

    </li>
    <li><a href=".profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a>

    </li>
    <li><a href=".messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a>

    </li>
    <li><a href=".settings" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a>

    </li>
  </ul>
  <!-- Tab panes -->
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active home">home
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>
      <!-- Modal -->
      <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
          <!-- Modal content-->
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
              <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane profile">profile
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2">Open Modal</button>
      <!-- Modal -->
      <div id="myModal2" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
          <!-- Modal content-->
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
              <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane messages">messages
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal3">Open Modal</button>
      <!-- Modal -->
      <div id="myModal3" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
          <!-- Modal content-->
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
              <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane settings">settings</div>
  </div>
  <hr>
</div>
```